# Cant access relations in 'created' Model Event?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Could someone please clarify this? I've used `Model Events` a lot of times before but it seems I haven't tried to access any related models on the initial "created" Event.

For example, I have two Models in a `M2M` relation to each other:

```
Book() public function authors()
Author() public function books()
```

I have saved a new Book object, with related authors, elsewhere in my code and by tapping into the "created" or "saved" Model Event (in EventServiceProvider.php), I would like to be able to update some fields in the related objects at the same time like this:

```
Book::created(function($book) {
    $authors = $book->authors;
    foreach($authors as $a){
        $a->books_authored += 1;
        $a->save();
    }
});
```

..but I can't, as $authors call returns no related objects. If this is the usual behaviour (and I haven't done something incorrect here)? Is there a way to get access to these relations on the initial creation/saving Event?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you are having is that the created event is firing before you have attached the authors. You haven't attached your code, but I'm assuming:

```
Book::create(['title' => 'Foo'])->author()->save(new Author['name' => 'Brian']);
```

This is actually the following:

```
$book = Book::create(['title' => 'Foo']) // Book created event fired
$relation = $book->author(); // Relation retrieved
$relation->save(new Author['name' => 'Brian']); //related author attached
```

You should probably manually fire an event when you attach an author in a function on your book model e.g.

```
class Book extends Eloquent
{
    public function saveAuthor($author) {
        if($this->save($author)) {
            Event::fire(new AuthorWasAttached($this, $author));
        }
    }
}
```

Then do your processing in the `AuthorWasAttached` event class

[This may be of help.](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/eloquent-attach-which-event-is-fired?page=1)

Comment: I have clarified my original question above. Hope its a bit easier to understand now.

Comment: Please add the code that shows how you create a book and link it to it's author. What you have added doesn't change my answer.

Comment: You are both quite right. The 'created' event is firing before the authors were attached and therefore the related items aren't available yet. I had forgotten that a new object has to be instantiated before any related objects are attached to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You create the book object and then;

```
$author=new Author(['name'=>'Joo']);
$book->authors()->save($author);
```

Comment: I don't want to create new author objects, I want to access the author relations that were already created in the Book::created Model Event and update some fields in them.